# Unable to start Kafka brokers using python script

Tags: python, apache-kafka, subprocess

I have started my own zookeeper setup and now i am trying to start Kafka brokers using python script and i am observing that its not connecting to zookeeper and all operations are failing.

```
    def start(self):
        cmd_split = shlex.split(self.cmd)
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_split, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        print("Running :", self.cmd)
        print("Started broker %d on PID : %d" % (self.broker_id, self.process.pid))

Running : /u/donthu/subs_logs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /u/donthu/subs_logs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/config/server.properties  --override broker.id=0 --override listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9080 --override log.dirs=/tmp/kafka0-logs
```

When i run the same command on console , its working fine.I think the problem lies in using subprocess module properly. Could anyone help to solve with the issue ?

Let me know if i need to provide much information regarding the issue.

Thanks in advance.